# R: Merging two vectors and shuffle them with a maximum number of repetitions

Tags: r

I want to merge two vectors in R. Each has 30 equal values, e.g.:

```
a <- rep("a",30)
b <- rep("b",30)
```

How do I achieve that there are never more than three consecutive appearances of a's or b's in the resulting vector?

```
c <- c("a","a","b","b","b","a","b","a","a",...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
f1 <- function(x,y, n1, n2 ){
 repeat {
   v1 <- sample(c(x,y),n1, replace=TRUE)
    if(all(rle(v1)$lengths <=n2)) break
    }
  return(v1)
}

res <- f1(a,b, 20, 3)
res
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
# "a" "b" "a" "b"
#[20] "a"
rle(res)$lengths
#[1] 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1
rle(f1(a,b, 30, 2))$lengths
#[1] 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1
```

Based on @jbest's comments, if you need the result to have equal number of "a", "b" elements,

```
 f1N <- function(x,y, n1, n2 ){
   repeat {
    v1 <- sample(c(x,y),n1, replace=TRUE)
    if(all(rle(v1)$lengths <=n2) & !diff(table(v1))) break
  }
  return(v1)
 }

 res <- f1N(a,b,36,2)
 table(res)
 #res
 # a  b 
 #18 18
```

#### Update

It may be also possible that you are not looking for a variable `n1`.  The below function will return a vector of `60` elements (30 of "a" and 30 of "b")

```
  f2 <- function(x, y, n){
  repeat {
   v1 <- sample(c(x,y))
    if(all(rle(v1)$lengths <=n)) break
   }
  return(v1)
 }
 res <- f2(a,b,3)
rle(res)$lengths
#[1] 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 1
 table(res)
 #res
 #a  b 
 #30 30
```

Comment: I think post indicate that their should be 30 equal values, possible to add after `if(sum(v1==a)==sum(v1==b))break`